# Attribute error what do these codes mean?

Tags: android, attributes, android-softkeyboard

```
"<Keyboard>" does not set the required layout_height attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "fill_parent"
"<Row>" does not set the required layout_width attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "fill_parent"
"<Row>" does not set the required layout_height attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "fill_parent"
"<Key>" does not set the required layout_width attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "fill_parent"
"<Key>" does not set the required layout_height attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "fill_parent"
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
You must supply a layout_height attribute.
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- Keyboard (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- Row (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- com.example.android.softkeyboard.LatinKeyboardView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

Comment: it cut off <Keyboard> at the beginning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that your xml keyboard layout file is missing `android:layout_width` and/or `android:layout_height` for some of the components.

**EDIT**

On second glance, it looks like you are putting your keyboard layout file in the `res/layout` folder. It belongs in the `res/xml` folder.

Answer (score 0):

an xml file in your project has elements which

"do not set the required layout_height attribute".

for each element, set it, for example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    **android:layout_height="fill_parent"**
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
```

Comment: I did that but no luck I have no idea why this softkeyboard will not show in graphical view and it keeps giving me errors..Im using the SDK keyboard sample... :(

Comment: oh after looking at it again I get it lets see what happens